# Connect to local ms sql server with php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, connection, localhost

I am trying to connect to a local MS SQL Server from php. The authentication is Windows authentication, and I don't know how to connect to the server(e.g. what to set as username and password, server name?)

```
$serverName = 'JOHN-PC\JOHN-PC';
$connectionOptions = array('website' => 'users');

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}
else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

The above code haven't even returned anything. So its like that the IF statement haven't been runned at all.

Please help me figure out how to connect.

Comment: Ever considered reading the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the first param as the `server` i believe your using `username` as the first param.

here is the method signature for reference.

```
resource mssql_connect ([ string $servername [, string $username [, string $password [, bool $new_link = false ]]]] )
```

Comment: I have seen it, it haven't helped. I don't know what to assign to what. (e.g. whats the servername in my case. the name of the pc is john-pc, and the name of the server is the same)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$connection = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=27.0.0.1;Database=myDataBase; Uid=userName;Pwd=thePassword;"); 
?>
```